# Is there a good algorithm to sort an unsorted, balanced, binary tree (that is better than just build a new tree)?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, tree

This may sound like a homework question, but honestly, it isn't.

I have a list of key/value pairs which i'm reading into a binary tree. I implemented an AVL tree for that, pretty straightforward - key, value as payload, left child, right child, balance factor and parent node for the tree itself. No problems here.

Now, i want to re-order the tree by a different criterion - assume a different comparison function, or i want to use (some part of) the value to sort the tree. Of course, i could just traverse my original tree in just about any order and add each node to a new AVL tree - after all, the code to build that is there. Or i could dump the tree into an array, `qsort()` the array, and use one of the many algorithms to efficiently generate a tree from a sorted array.

But, for reasons that are too complicated to explain here, i'd rather not allocate a 2nd structure, instead, i want to sort the tree in itself. The standard sorting algorithms seem not to make much sense here, since they generally rely on operations like "select the n-th element", "advance one element", "back up one element", which are cheap in an array, but rather costly in a binary tree.

Googling didn't help much - there are zillions of web pages that explain binary trees, B-trees, AVL trees, red-black trees and how to use them to sort data. I don't need these pages, i know the basics. But if there is an article, somewhere, that explains "how to sort an unsorted tree, so the result is sorted and balanced", those zillions of pages do a great job of hiding it.

So if there is any good algorithm to re-sort an unsorted tree while keeping it balanced, i'd like to hear about it - and if this algorithm needs less time than one of the "just build a new one" attempts, all the better.

(No, i have no code to show since i'm searching for an algorithm; the AVL-tree-building code i have wouldn't contribute to the problem, and once i find a suitable algorithm i'm quite certain i will be able to implement it - i just need a starting point).

Comment: All of this will `O(n log n)` anyhow. Algorithms on dynamic DS are always a good factor slower than anything array based, because of all the indirections. I'd go for a simple way: array of pointer to your tree nodes, adequate `comp` function, `qsort`. You can't expect anything more efficient than that.

Comment: You should be able to free memory as you go if you use a 2nd BST. And memory is really the only good reason I can think of to want to avoid this (apart from some sort of terrible, terrible design), so perhaps you should elaborate a bit on your reasons. But this is an interesting problem nonetheless.

Comment: @Dukeling: It's going to be a library for an embedded device that collects data until the assigned memory block is "full", and i can't rely on the device to provide more memory, even temporary. I'd rather allow the data collection part fill *all* the memory assigned to the lib than reserve some space for resorting later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity cannot be better than `O(n*log n)` because the binary search tree(BST) you are going to build is based on comparison of keys and the original tree is not **ordered** at all (which is ordered in another irrelevant criterion). The method has three steps and build a BST from a binary tree(BT) **in place** (and this is what you want).

1. Convert your AVL tree to a double linked list (DLL). This can be done in `O(n)` by any traversal algorithm and use the left/right child pointer of AVL tree as previous/next pointer of a DLL.
2. Merge sort the DLL in `O(n*log n)` time. Please refer to the [sort an linked list](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/).
3. Convert the sorted DLL to a binary search tree (e.g., AVL) in `O(n)`. Please refer to [convert sorted list into BST](http://leetcode.com/2010/11/convert-sorted-list-to-balanced-binary.html).

Comment: i was about to post very similar solution :)

Comment: Convert the tree to a list, sort it, rebuild the tree is a nice solution to the problem that doesn't need extra memory, so i'll use this.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to move the nodes of the tree one by one into the new tree that is sorted. Yes, I know that's technically another tree, but you would never increase the number of nodes allocated, and never copy any memory, just switch pointers about. So apart from an additional root node you aren't 'allocating a 2nd structure'.

I'm wildly guessing at what you are doing here, but perhaps you are changing your sort key. If so, it's possible to have tree pointers for two (or more) trees with the same set of nodes, so a node can be in 2 (or more) trees at once, sorted both times, and differently sorted. That may also be useful.